# Crontab on shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

i have problem with crontable in shell
I always write cronjob like this

```
0 * * * * /tmp/myscript
```

but now im on different shell and to use my script i need write like this

```
bash-4.2$ bash /tmp/myscript
```

And thats problem because when I write cronjob like this

```
* * * * * /tmp/myscript or bash /tmp/myscript ---> thats not work
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must use this structure for Crontab:

```
* * * * * user-name command to be executed
```

By the way, first, you should rename myscript to myscript.sh and run it.

For example:

```
17 * * * * root bash /tmp/myscript.sh
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but note that there's no need to rename `myscript` since extensions are irrelevant. You can even do `bash myscript.exe` as long as `myscript.exe` contains valid bash.

Comment: Yeah, i do like this and cron work in log
Oct 10 10:00:01 SERV_NAME CROND[14025]: (user) CMD (user echo " " >> /tmp/myscript_result.txt)

But the file has not been edited